Spring boot - ClassNotFoundExcpetion and NoClassDefFoundError with Jakarta validation
I currently have a Spring boot app and I'm trying to run the unit tests. Obviously they'll fail since the application itself cannot run due to the 2 errors mentioned in the title.
The application is one micro service
As I run the application, I get those 3 errors in the following order:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
2. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/validation/ValidationException
3. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.validation.ValidationException

What I tried:
I tried updating my dependencies, by removing and adding other dependencies. I did what others wrote online (mostly other stack overflow questions). Below are my relevant dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


I also notice in my project that I am importing this line here:
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
and the @NotNull annotation is used on a String property. That may have something to do with it
My guess is that there's something going wrong with the validation

Remove the dependencies you have add spring-boot-starter-validation. Fix the imports to use jakarta.validation instead of javax.validation.

Which version of Spring Boot? It seems that you have a mix of javax.validation and jakarta.validation which causes these problems. When using Spring Boot before 3.0 you should use javax.validation exclusively and when using Spring Boot 3.0 or later you should be using jakarta.validation exclusively (in case you are wondering: this is the successor of javax.validation)

I'm using Spring Boot 2

Then still remove the dependencies and use spring-boot-starter-validation. The jakarta.validation stuff comes from newer dependencies. Generally you should stick with Spring Boot starters to add dependencies instead of manually searching and adding dependencies.

I removed both dependencies and I'm using spring-boot-starter-validation and I'm getting the same issue. I can't find any imports in my application that uses jakarta validation. it doesn't make sense

It seems that one of your dependencies is already depending on jakarta.validation. You could use the Maven Dependency Plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) to create a list of all dependencies, search that list for that library that depends on jakarta.validation and then try to replace that library with a version that still depends on java.validation
